# Song that plays in the battle between Goku and Zamasu?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In episode 53, Goku fights a Kai in training named Zamasu. Does anyone know the name of the music that played about halfway into the battle? I really liked it but I can't seem to find a title anywhere.

Attached below is a link to a YouTube video showing the fight. The music kicks up around 1:25–2:18 in the video.

> [Video: Goku vs Zamasu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuCRKzQ6uUM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! The song is called `Desperate Assault`.

**EDIT:** Link here [Desperate Assault OST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXHTJ-snUKQ)